# Randomly Assign Title To UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uibutton

On iOS, is it possible to have the title for a UIButton be randomized a little?  Each view will have 4 UIButtons, and 4 values from a key in NSDictionary that I would like to assign to the UIButtons, but have it be random for each button, so that in different runnings of the app, the UIButtons might appear in different order.  How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Use random class to generate an index between 1 & 4 as per your requirements. Put the titles in a list. Then based on the randomly generated number, lookup the title at the index and assign the titles for the UIButtons.
This way everytime you will have a different order. However, do not forget to check whether, the  number has been already assigned or not.

Cheers! Hope it helps.

Comment: Not quite sure I'm understanding what you're meaning

Comment: what I mean is, use the random class or its equivalent to generate a random number between 1 and 4. You can use the randomly generated number as index for a list. put the 4 values in a list and then based on the index assign UIbutton1 = list[randomindex] and so on. Use an if to see if the index has been previously assigned or not.

Comment: For "random class " perhaps the Chris means `arc4random_uniform()` where the argument is the range. See [man arc4random](https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/arc4random.3.html).